# Python, OpenCV: stopping capture at end of file

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-capture

(Using OpenCV 4.1)

I am trying to capture screenshots from videos. My intention is to have the script capture a frame every five minutes up to 20 captures.

My test video is 20 minutes long. Once the script loops 4 times, I want it to quit. However, it loops a 5th time and captures 2 seconds from the end of the video. Then it loops a 6th time and captures the same frame as the 4th loop. It keeps repeating these last two loops until there are 20 frames captured.

How do I get the script to recognize that it has reached the end of the video and stop?

Note: the last frame captured may not be the last frame in the video. For example, if the video is 23 minutes long, the last frame captured should be near the 20-minute mark.

```
import datetime
import sys
import time

from cv2 import cv2


def milsec_to_hr_min_sec(milliseconds):  # Returned from CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC
    ms = int(milliseconds)
    seconds = str(int((ms / 1000) % 60))
    minutes = str(int((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60))
    hours = str(int((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24))
    return hours, minutes, seconds


def FrameCapture(path):  # Extract frame
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    framerate = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    count = 1
    framecount = 0

    # checks whether frames were extracted
    while True:
        while count < 21 and framecount < cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT):
            # Capture frame every 5 minutes
            framecount = count * framerate * 60 * 5
            cap.set(1, framecount)

            # capture frame at timestamp
            success, image = cap.read()
            if success:
                cv2.imwrite(
                    path + " (screencap #%d).jpg" % count, image,
                )
                # Convert timestamp to hr:min:sec
                hours, minutes, seconds = milsec_to_hr_min_sec(
                    cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
                )
                print(
                    str(success)
                    + " "
                    + "Captured: screencap #{} at timestamp ".format(count)
                    + hours
                    + "h "
                    + minutes
                    + "m "
                    + seconds
                    + "s"
                )
                count += 1
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                    break
            else:
                break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Finished capture")


# Driver Code
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Calling the function
    fn = "\\full\path\to\file"
    FrameCapture(fn)
```

*Please forgive the hack-y nature of my scripts. I pieced them together with parts found from searches.*

Comment: What do you mean by _Once the script loops 4 times_? It would be good to have some test data, too. See: [mcve].

Comment: You aren't checking whether or not you've passed the end of the video. Before you set the frame number, check that there are that many frames in your video. I.e., change your while loop condition maybe to something like `while count < 21 and framecount < totalframes`

Comment: @AlexanderCécile By _test data_, do you mean a copy of the video? Also, the script captures a screenshot of the video every loop (count ==1, count ==2, etc.) Since the video is 20 min long and the script captures 1 frame every 5 min of video time, there should be 4 frames captured.

Comment: @GBMedusa Yeah, just anything that could allow us to run the program properly.

Comment: @alkasm I tried your recommendation and it worked. After I made the change, I had another issue that the script would stop looping as I wanted but it would hang at the beginning of the 2nd (modified) while loop. I added `if count > 20 or framecount > total_frames - 1: break` to leave the loop and the script is working so far.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes you must consider the last frame; `>=` would also work in that case! You don't need a while loop and an if statement though, you can directly check that as the while condition!

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the "while" loop you may use the following code:

```
ret, frames = cap.read()

if frames is None:

    break
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it:

- Loop through a `while(true)` loop and `break` when `frame.empty()`.
- Obtain the frame count using: `int nFrames = vid_cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); //Get the number of frames avaiable in the video` and use a `for_loop` to loop through the frames.

Answer (score 0):

This code will get all frames from your video

```
def get_list_frame_by_video(file_path_video):
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path_video)
    list_frame = []

    print("____start load video____")
    len_frames = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    while True:
        is_cap, frame = vs.read()
        if frame is None:
            continue
        list_frame.append(frame)
        if len_frames == len(list_frame):
            break

    print("____complete load video____")
    return list_frame
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is:

```
    sucess, img = cap.read()
    if img is None:
        print(' Successful process  ')
        break
```

You just have to add this line and process will be ended if 'cap' is empty